# visual studio team services: update json file from ci variables

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Team Services, we can update web.config appSetting parameters with the values defined in variables (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/change-config-azure-webapps).

Is there any way to update json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Tokenize task works with json file too. You just need to add a Tokenize task in your definition and set the "Source filename" to your json file.